Missing information in AWS-Xray
I have .net 6 web api running in a aws lambda. I have enabled the x-ray tracing in lambda and also made code changes in api
AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseXRay("my-api");

When I run this locally using aws-xray-daemon all the details comes up in x-ray logs. but when it run on deployed version details are logged but httpmethod and url fields are blank
Blank items are when deployed api is consumed. Is there anything I need to add here

